# Setting ARSCNView scene background contents to iPhone X camera

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scenekit, arkit

ARSCNView automatically renders the live video feed from the device camera as the scene background. But I'm trying to **manually** set the scene background contents to one of the iPhone X cameras. I can successfully set sceneView.scene.background.contents to colors, images, etc. but not to the live front or back camera. I have tried setting sceneView.scene.background.contents to be an AVCaptureDevice, AVCaptureDeviceInput, and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. I also tried an independent AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in another view. None of these result in simultaneous camera video and face tracking.

I sense it could have something to do with ARFaceTrackingConfiguration() automatically using the front camera with no way to show separate camera video concurrently? I think there was some sort of bug fixed with iOS 11.2, but I I'm having no success with 11.3. Depending on my approach I get one of:

- both video and face tracking freeze
- face tracking works but the video freezes
- video works but face tracking freezes
- a few video frames and/or facemask frames before they freeze

---

**Swift4/iOS11/iPhone X**

**setting scene.background.contents directly:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  sceneView.delegate = self
  sceneView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration())

  // wait for scene and camera to activate
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(. builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front)!
    self.sceneView.scene.background.contents = captureDevice
  }
}
```

**using separate video layer:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var inp: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  sceneView.delegate = self
  sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIColor.yellow
  sceneView.session.run(ARFaceTrackingConfiguration())

  if let cam = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front) {
    do { inp = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: cam) }
    catch { fatalError("Failed to get device input") }
  } else { fatalError("Failed to get camera device") }

  captureSession.addInput(inp)
  videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
  videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.bounds
  videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
    self.captureSession.startRunning()
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.videoPreviewLayer!)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you can only use one camera at a time?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW25

> Note: Media capture does not support simultaneous capture of both the front-facing and back-facing cameras on iOS devices.